# Why I can't use the Mysql data library?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, dll

A have a project which have to connect mysql server. For this I have to import the Mysql.data.dll. I did it. And after that I want to run my project the compiler says "`Error  2   The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project_name\Project_name\Db_Handling.cs    6   7`". But the dll among the added references and I imported it with using. And the same happened in vs 2012 and 2013, although I have an other project with this dll.
I (want to )use the 6.7.2.0 version of mysql dll if it help anything.

Comment: are you targeting to `.NET Framework client profile` check in project properties -> target framework?

Comment: That's a possible reason. If this is the solution, what framework should I target? Because I use the default .net versions in the vs( which means 4.0 in 2012 and 4.5 in 2013 I guess).

Comment: Now I see. I retargeted the version, but the problem is the same :(

Comment: i think you should not target to client profile versions.

Comment: but before it I used the "basic" 4.0 version. The vs recognize that I added the dll as reference, I can write the using statement as well, but when I want to compile, the problem occurs.

Comment: can you `clean` and `rebuild` the whole solution?

Comment: unfortunately nope :( When I want to rebuild, there is the same problem.

Comment: hm... I try to install the 6.8.3 version and maybe that solves this problem...

Comment: Yes yes, that's the solution... Refreshed the version and all working. Many thanks for the help, and patience :) :)

Comment: added my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** as you said you have already added the `Mysql` dll and referenced required namespaces by `using` statement, i think the only problem is IDE is not pickingup the latest MySQL references added to the project.

**Solution :**  you can `clean` and `rebuild` the whole solution to get the recently added references into your projet.